# C I need to use malloc and a dynamically allocated array however I need to print the user input

Tags: c, malloc

So pretty much that. I need to ask a user for the numberof elements then ask them the ints they want and finally print out all the ints.

This is my code so far:

```
int main(void)
{
  int user_input = 0, elements = 0;
  printf("How many int elements will you enter?\n");
  scanf("%d", &elements);

  int* dynamic_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(double)* elements);

  for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
  {
    printf("Element %d?\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &dynamic_array[i], i + 1);
  }

  for (int printf_number = 1; printf_number <= elements; printf_number++)
  {
    printf("Element %d: %d\n", printf_number, (dynamic_array[user_input]));
  }

  free(dynamic_array);
  dynamic_array = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code here.

Comment: And what is the problem you have with the code? Can you please elaborate? And please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It says the code is too long, the error is that only one element prints, not all of them and I don't know how to make all of them print.

Comment: Who/what is "it"?

Comment: @ChetanTakyar post the relevant part of your code then (the one you have a problem with).

Comment: Well this website, I was gonna reply to the person with my code but when I tried to paste it in, the message box said that I had used too many characters

Comment: `printf("How many int elements will you enter?\n");`
 `scanf("%d", &elements);`

 `int* dynamic_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(double)* elements);`


 `for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)`
 `{`
  `printf("Element %d?\n", i + 1);`
  `scanf("%d", &dynamic_array[i], i + 1);`
  
 `}`

 `for (int printf_number = 1; printf_number <= elements; printf_number++)`
 {
  `printf("Element %d: %d\n", printf_number, (dynamic_array[user_input]));`
 }

 `free(dynamic_array);`
 `dynamic_array = 0;`
 `return 0;`
`}`

Comment: That is cos you should edit the question, rather than posting it as a comment - cos as a comment it looks hideous and unformatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue 1: you are allocating `sizeof(double)` to store int
issue 2: You are not traversing array to print numbers

```
int main(void)
{
  int user_input = 0, elements = 0;
  printf("How many int elements will you enter?\n");
  scanf("%d", &elements);

  int* dynamic_array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)* elements);
  if(dynamic_array == NULL) {
     perror(" Out of memory ");
     return 0;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
  {
    printf("Element %d?\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &dynamic_array[i]);
  }

  for (int printf_number = 0; printf_number < elements; printf_number++)
  {
    printf("Element %d: %d\n", printf_number+1, dynamic_array[printf_number]);
  }

  free(dynamic_array);
  dynamic_array = 0;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. Sorry it actually does just made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int printf_number = 1; printf_number <= elements; printf_number++) 
{ 
    printf("Element %d: %d\n", printf_number, (dynamic_array[user_input])); 
}
```

Your index `printf_number` should start at zero and the condition must be`printf_number < elements`. And you must use `printf_number` to index the array, not `user_input`. Note that `user_input` is not initialized.

Why allocate an array with `sizeof(double)` when you only read ints?

Comment: Wait one second

Comment: It should not be a double. On my screen I do not have a double